# How to convert tooltip to onclick event in high charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

[I have an column highchart on mouseover entire month values are showing i want one place value on click event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsynA.png)I am having mouse over functionality. I need the tooltip on mouse click event in Highcharts.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Mouse events demo'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'On point mouse click, the values should be reported in top left'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        var chart = this.series.chart;
                        if (!chart.lbl) {
                            chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('')
                                .attr({
                                    padding: 10,
                                    r: 10,
                                    fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                                })
                                .css({
                                    color: '#FFFFFF'
                                })
                                .add();
                        }
                        chart.lbl
                            .show()
                            .attr({
                                text: 'x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y
                            });
                    }
                }
            },
            events: {
                mouseOut: function() {
                    if (this.chart.lbl) {
                        this.chart.lbl.hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

The code is available on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-mouseover/) too. Instead of mouse hover I want on click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the JavaScript part in that fiddle with Below Code

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
title: {
    text: 'Mouse events demo'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'On point mouse over or mouse out, the values should be reported in top left'
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
               click: function () {
                    var chart = this.series.chart;
                    if (!chart.lbl) {
                        chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('')
                            .attr({
                                padding: 10,
                                r: 10,
                                fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                            })
                            .css({
                                color: '#FFFFFF'
                            })
                            .add();
                    }
                    chart.lbl
                        .show()
                        .attr({
                            text: 'x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y
                        });
                }
            }
        },
        events: {
            mouseOut: function () {
                if (this.chart.lbl) {
                    this.chart.lbl.hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }
},

tooltip: {
    enabled: false
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
});
```

Just Changed the Mouseover function to click

Comment: hi Sindhoor thank you very much can you help this too
I have an API response like this http://www.mocky.io/v2/59705b29100000370471d90f  I need tooltip on mouse over and values to be shown on click event too. I tried by putting tooltip and click event on plot options not working

Comment: I have attached an image

Comment: why unmarked answer? u will never get any help if u do so

Comment: along with the x and y axis i want to print x axis categories also in the chart label can you help this too. when i am putting this showing error
text: 'x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y + ', field: ' + this.xAxis.categories

Comment: In the response i alredy have this
xAxis: {
 categories: ["Delivery Truck", "Express Air", "Regular Air"]
},

Comment: when i click on first bar along with x and y i want to get Delivery Truck too.

Comment: i am waiting for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here, You need to change two thing.

1. Click event: i have show alert here where you can take action according to whatever you want to show tooltip in your format
2. Disable tool tip: This is to hide default tool tip on mouse move

Fiddle demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/77mq9k3a/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/77mq9k3a/1/)

Code snippet:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'Mouse events demo'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'On point mouse click, the values should be reported in top left'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      events: {
        click: function(event) {
          alert(
            this.name + ' clicked\n' +
            'Alt: ' + event.altKey + '\n' +
            'Control: ' + event.ctrlKey + '\n' +
            'Meta: ' + event.metaKey + '\n' +
            'Shift: ' + event.shiftKey
          );
        }
      }
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]

});
```

You can find highchart API here. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.click